# repeating a formula conditionally in excel 2013?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to calculate a formula and then dragging it to apply it for the whole column but the problem is that I want to compare first cell of the column A with the first cell of the column B and then second cell of the column A with the second cell of the column B and then compare third cell of the column a with the first cell of the column B... :

```
    A    B      result
1   1    4        0
2   2    5        0
3   3             0
4   4             0 
5   5             1
6   5             1
```

when i write the pattern like if `=IF((A1<Sheet1!B1),0,1)` then `=IF((A2<Sheet1!B2),0,1)` ,`=IF((A1<Sheet1!B1),0,1)`,`=IF((A2<Sheet1!B2),0,1)`
Four times and then dragging the formula for the column it start comparing it with the correspond one `=IF((A5<Sheet1!B5),0,1)` How should i change it ?

**edit** :

in the example I want to compare cell(1,A) with cell(1,B) then cell (2,A) with cell (2,B) and then cell(3,A) with cell(1,B) then cell (4,A) with cell (2,B) and then cell(5,A) with cell(1,B) then cell (6,A) with cell (2,B).[repeating the pattern two times and then start over]

Comment: so what is the expected result that you are looking for?

Comment: @AHC, please see the edit part

Comment: @pnuts - The way I read this, A3 (*3*) is less than B1 (*4*) so the result is *zero*. However, A4 (*4*) is less than B2 (*5*) so it should be zero as well.

Comment: yes @pnuts it is in a diffrent sheet, i didn't get your second question?

Comment: @pnuts, My bad , result was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in C1,

```
=--NOT(A1<OFFSET('Different Sheet'!$B$1, MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 2), 0))
```

Fill down as necessary. You only seem to be looking for a *0* or a *1* so I've simplified your `IF` statement. (Note: maths with MOD adjusted for more universality)

For different multiples you should only have to change the *divisor* parameter of the [MOD function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767.aspx). The [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/row-function-7f5b93c1-0cfa-4e83-8d81-a072213b9ab6) used as `ROW(1:1)` will return *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc* as you fill down. MOD returns the remainder of a division operation so `MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, 3)` filled down will return *0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, etc*.

If you used the [COUNT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-function-e154a8e3-7a15-4555-bbfb-809c7a7b04eb) on the numbers in 'Different Sheet'!B:B, you should be able to achieve a dynamic divisor.

```
=--NOT(A1<OFFSET('Different Sheet'!$B$1, MOD(ROW(1:1)-1, COUNT('Different Sheet'!B:B)), 0))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the column B actually is in the different sheet.

Comment: @academic.user - It isn't hard to reference another worksheet.

Comment: thanks @Jeeped, sorry but i am not an expert and have problem modifying it  when for example the second column is three row and we  want to compare the same but repeating 3.let say repeating some formula for n times and starting over.

Comment: @academic.user - I've modified the math in the [MOD function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634767.aspx) so you just need to change the **2** in the MOD's *divisor* parameter. See my explanation above. If need be you could actually use a [COUNT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-function-e154a8e3-7a15-4555-bbfb-809c7a7b04eb) to supply the divisor.

Comment: I mocked up pretty much the same formula except that I replaced the volatile OFFSET function with an INDEX function like: `=IF(A1<INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNT(Sheet1!B:B))+1),0,1)`. Could make a significant performance difference if and when this spreadsheet gets scaled up.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff - Good point! I try to avoid the volatile [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) in favor of a comparable [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) but I missed it this time.